# VBA статическая переменная в Модуле Access

Tags: sql, access, vba, office

У меня есть Module в котором описана функция для работы с Access.
Данной функции подается на вход подается строка, которая затем анализируется(Сплитится, проводятся различные преобразования), а потом эта преобразованная строка ищется в специальной таблице, где 50 записей (SpecTable).
Локально это все прекрасно работает, а вот если база находится на шаре(Т.е работа происходит через инет), то функция работает медленно.
Я провел анализ и обнаружил, что на каждую преобразованную запись приходится обращение к SpecTable.
Можно ли как-нибудь хитро сделать 1 инициализацию всей таблицы в память(допустим массив), что бы таблица считывалась только 1 раз, а вся последующая работа с функцией работала с памятью?
Т.е к примеру

```
select top 100 parseword(str) from table
```

В первый раз будет прочитана таблица SpecTable, а в последующих 99 обращений к функции будет использоваться непосредственно массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы попробовал такие варианты:

1. Если таблица статична, хранить её копию на клиенте.
2. Создать представление (запрос) на клиенте и уже к нему адресовать запросы.
3. Использовать recordset, т,е. курсор на клиенте.